# Prevent scrolling in popup window when using iScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

I'm using iScroll for mobile-friendly scrolling, and have an odd issue. Not only am I using iScroll for the main portion of a site, but I'm also using it for popups. However, scrolling within the popup also triggers scrolling in the main site underneath.

Is there a way to prevent this kind of bubbling?

Comment: did my response answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for `event.stopPropagation()` (a native JS method that keeps the event from bubbling any further up into the DOM)?

> Prevents further propagation of the current event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

Could you edit your question to include some code in order to give a little more context? Thx